# Problem with WINDOWS debug symbol loading. I could not load WINDOWS operating system binaries .pdb in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, pdb-files, crash-dumps, debug-symbols

I am working in a software company on a system software product. Day before yesterday that product got crashed and core shown.

To findout exact problem, I want to know full core stack with function names(kernel32.dll, ntdll.dll .. not showing function names). I have downloaded WINDOWS debug symbols from Microsoft site.
http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/symbolpkg.mspx#f

Downloaded following three packages
1. WindowsServer2003-KB933548-v1-ia64-symbols-NRL-ENU.exe
2. WindowsServer2003-KB933548-v1-x86-symbols-NRL-ENU.exe
3. WindowsServer2003-KB933548-v1-x86-symbols-NRL-ENU-DEBUG.exe.

Tried to load debug symbols for the WINDOWS OS binaries, but I could not succeeded. 
 Example : for  ntdll.dll I tried to load corresponding ntdll.pdb but Visual studio throughing error i.e "The symbol file ntdll.pdb does not match the module)

Operating system: I am using WINDOWS 2003 SP2 .

Please please help to get full stack with function names.

### Core Stack after crash on my system software.

kernel32.dll!77e4bef7()  Asm
  [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for kernel32.dll] Asm
  kernel32.dll!77e4bef7()  Asm
  kernel32.dll!77e46cfd()  Asm
  ntdll.dll!7c827d29()  Asm
  ntdll.dll!7c83d266()  Asm
  ntdll.dll!7c83d2b1()  Asm
  ntdll.dll!7c82d308()  Asm
  ntdll.dll!7c82d30f()  Asm
  ntdll.dll!7c82f380()  Asm
  ntdll.dll!7c82d30f()  Asm
  ntdll.dll!7c82f557()  Asm
  ntdll.dll!7c82a501()  Asm
  ntdll.dll!7c82daee()  Asm
  ntdll.dll!7c82f51a()  Asm
  ntdll.dll!7c82f2c3()  Asm
  kernel32.dll!77e6518d()  Asm
  ntdll.dll!7c829cc2()  Asm
  ntdll.dll!7c829de7()  Asm
  ntdll.dll!7c829e02()  Asm
  ntdll.dll!7c827899()  Asm
  ntdll.dll!7c82ec4a()  Asm
  msvcr80.dll!781787e4()  Asm
  msvcr80.dll!78178823()  Asm
  sal.dll!SAL_DebugOutput(const char * fmtstr=0x66009318, ...)  Line 643 C++
  sal.dll!MapSystemError(unsigned long dwerr=0x00000040)  Line 130 + 0xb bytes C++

### sal.dll!MapLastError()  Line 146 + 0xc bytes C++

sal.dll is a my software binary and I was able to load debug symbol for sal.dll.

I waiting for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use symbol server to get this rather than downloading a static set.  (A static set quickly becomes outdated with servicing.)

Here is a KB article about using Symbol Server:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503

There is support in both Visual studio and Windbg for this.